# Cannot uninstall XP SP3 update

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, sp3

I need to uninstall Service Pack 3 because it broke a program I rely on (FrameMaker).  I have done this before on other computers using [Microsoft's SP3 uninstall instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950249).  However, on this computer, SP3 is not listed in Add/Remove Programs (and, yes, I have checked the "Show Updates" checkbox), there's no "$NtServicePackUninstall$" restore directory, and either Windows didn't create a restore point for the SP3 install or it has fallen off of the list of restorable points.

Does anyone know of any other options?

Comment: wfaulk - Try booting in Safe mode, and see if SP3 gets listed now.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think you are out of luck if the situation you said is true.

It is also possible that you are dealing with a machine that actually was a SP3 integrated install so it is not possible to remove it.

It may be worth checking with Adobe if there are any updates to Framemaker... You really shouldn't sacrifice the security of your computer for an application, if you really need Framemaker and it won't run natively, you can always try [Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org).

However, I have a client who uses Framemaker CS4. It seems to work on XP. What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

If it's Framemaker 8, Adobe have posted a patch.

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4549

If an earlier version like 6 or 7 then i'd look to upgrade. A search online reveals this problem may relate to a security fix for OLE, and obviously your system is more vulnerable without it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Start Menu >> Run, type c:\windows\$NtServicePackUninstall$\spuninst\spuninst.exe and press Enter
2. This will start the windows XP service pack 3 removal wizard and click Next
3. Follow the instructions on the screen to remove windows service pack 3

Comment: As stated in the question, there is no SP3 restore directory.  I updated the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to resolve the issue with Framemaker rather than remove the service pack?